# JPA value from a findByID is not updated after a query

Tags: java, spring, jpa

I try to update a value inside a method by using a custom query. The value is updated but when in the same method I update the value and then I make a findById my object is not updated but in my table, it's updated. I don't understand why?

My repository :

```
@Repository
public interface CarRepository extends JpaRepository<Car, Long> {


    @Modifying
    @Query("update Car c set c.idRefStateCarFk =:idStateCar WHERE c.id =:idCar")
    int updateStatutSaisineBPCA(@Param("idCar") long idCar, @Param("idStateCar") long idStateCar );
}
```

My function :

```
@Service
@Transactional
@AllArgsConstructor
public class CarService{



public void completeAndSaveCar(DocumentDTO documentDTO) throws Exception {
            int i = carRepository.updateStateCar(car.getId(), 1L);
            carRepository.findById(car.getId());
        }
    }
```

In my function, I get int i = 1, so my update is done but when I'm doing a findById the state of my object is not updated and I don't know why?

Comment: Because it is updated in the table. The object comes from the first level cache and not the database, as you are directly updating the database instead of updating the object in the 1st level cache. So now there is a mismatch in state.

Comment: Thank you for your answer , so how should i do it in order to update both of them ? Should i change my query ?

Comment: Just findById then update the object and the database will auto-updated.

Comment: Trying to make sense of the code sample. Is updateStateCar supposed to be updateStatutSaisineBPCA?

Comment: You only need to update the object, JPA will synchronize it to the database.